# Is there software to convert Pagemaker to any document format (doc, docx, or odt)?

Tags: document-converter, file-converter

This is a very long shot. I have a lot of old publications that were produced with Adobe Pagemaker 6.0 or 7.0. I do not have the software and it is no longer downloadable from Adobe site. Is there by any chance any software that would convert Pagemaker into some more accessible document format (doc or odt)?

**Note**: OS can be Windows/Mac/Linux and software can be paid or free.

Comment: I remember that Microsoft had a large conversion add-in for Word 6.0.  Perhaps it could help you.  I don't recall if it converted from Pagemaker 6.0.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard. The trouble with that, is I would need Word 6.0 which must be completely unobtainable today

Comment: The conversion add-in might have been standalone; I cannot recall. I would think a Word 6.0 license would be very inexpensive nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get InDesign CS6 (not higher). InDesign CC does not have .pm6, .p65, or .pmd as input format. You can sill get the trial versions here: https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/cs6-product-downloads.html

After you can [export](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/exporting.html) it to different formats from plain text to advanced formats.